# Opening saved QGIS layout in layout designer with Python

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Is it possible to open saved layout in layout designer(print composer) with Python?

QGIS Python API:

> ```
> openLayoutDesigner(self, layout: QgsMasterLayoutInterface) → QgsLayoutDesignerInterface
> ```
>
> Opens a new layout designer dialog for the specified layout, or brings
> an already open designer window to the foreground if one is already
> created for the layout.
>
> New in version 3.0.

I have tried `iface.openLayoutDesigner("layoutname")` in python console, but I get error:

> TypeError: QgisInterface.openLayoutDesigner(): argument 1 has
> unexpected type 'str'

I don't understand what argument 1 should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get the layout to open, first. Then pass the layout instance to `openLayoutDesigner()` method. You can't open a layout by passing its name to that method. The method expect you to pass `QgsMasterLayoutInterface` instance.

Try in this way:

```
l_out = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName("layoutname")
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout=l_out)
```

Comment: Thanks it works now.
Because i want this inside plugin, I added self before openLayoutDesigner.
    `self.iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout=l_out)`

Comment: To have iface inside a plugin, you can do "from qgis.utils import iface". No need to always have it in "self".